# Change the label of a TCollectionItem in the Delphi editor

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, tcollectionitem

A component I am working on uses a TCollection to hold links to other components. When the items are edited in the designer their labels look something like this:

```
0 - TComponentLink
1 - TComponentLink
2 - TComponentLink
3 - TComponentLink
```

How do I add meaningful labels (the name of the linked component perhaps)? e.g.

```
0 - UserList
1 - AnotherComponentName
2 - SomethingElse
3 - Whatever
```

As a bonus, can you tell me how to make the collection editor appear when the component is double clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To display a meaningful name override GetDisplayName:

```
function TMyCollectionItem.GetDisplayName: string; 
begin 
  Result := 'My collection item name'; 
end;
```

To display a collection editor when the non visual component is double clicked you need to override the TComponentEditor Edit procedure.

```
TMyPropertyEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
public
  procedure Edit; override; // <-- Display the editor here
end;
```

... and register the editor:

```
RegisterComponentEditor(TMyCollectionComponent, TMyPropertyEditor);
```

Answer (score 1):

The name displayed in the editor is stored in the item's DisplayName property.  Try setting your code to set something like this when you create the link:

```
item.DisplayName := linkedItem.Name;
```

Be careful not to change the DisplayName if the user's already set it, though.  That's a major UI annoyance.

Comment: Thanks Mason, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. It dod however lead me to an answer that did work. Simply override the TCollectionItem "GetDisplayName" function e.g.

function TMyCollectionItem.GetDisplayName: string;
begin
  Result := 'My collection item name';
end;